# How to write these code in DAL ,BAL and UI layer seperately

Tags: c#-4.0

Sqlconnectioncon=new sqlconnnection(conn);

Sqlcommand cmd=new sqlcommand(select name from project where name like '"+gridview.rows[e.rows].cells ["name"]+"',con);

SqlDataAdapter sda=new sqlDataAdapter(cmd);

Dataset ds=new Dataset()
sda.Fill(ds,"table");

Datarow row=ds.Tables["table"].rows[0];

nametextbox.text=row["name"]
.Tostring();

addresstextbox.text=row
["address"].Tostring();

Comment: First of all, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It's unclear what you're asking on this description

Comment: I assume you're talking about 3-tier architecture. If so, DAL means data access layer, BLL (not BAL) means business logic layer, UI means the user interface layer. There are logical and physical separation guidelines on these layers. Please google on 3-tier architecture. Rough guideline might be, use 3 different projects (2 class libraries and one windows form/asp project) to implement these layers.